# to maintain application hit counter if IIS crash ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis

to maintain a web site hit counter we can keep that variable in application['hitcounter'] and save it using appliaction_end event to database if application reset and reload it in application_start event from database and then update it whenever it website get hit from a user. my question is what if 'IIS' crash then using which event i save the current value of 'hitcounter' to database?

Comment: if IIS crashes there won't be a web server (or worker process) to execute the page so the answer is you don't.

Comment: write it out to a flat file or database (crappy overhead). Then query it on Application_Start()

Comment: I wouldn't ever rely on something happening Application_End or Session_End if it's important to you. They typically will fire, but not in all cases, like crashes as mentioned.

Comment: Besides, if the IIS Application crashes, the ["hitcounter"] will be back to "0" because all users will be kicked off... When IIS restarts, you can reload all your hits on `Session_Start()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't guarantee the application works well enough to do anything during a crash. As an extreme scenario, imagine the server crashes as a result of the power cord being pulled, that the last byte of hard drive space has been used up, etc.

You can save your hitcounter to the database more often. If you don't want to incur a database hit too often (say on every request), you can save it to the database every 10, 100 or 1000 hits, just by putting the save routine on BeginRequest event handler and save only when the number is divisible by 10, or 100.

Answer (score 2):

Either write it to a file or to a database. When IIS crashes any application information stored in memory will be lost.